# Select TOP predicate

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with fields StudentID, ClassID, ExamID, SubjectID and Scores
I am trying to get a sum of 7 top Scores from attempted  subjects from every student. The SQL statement below is giving me the sum of scores of all the subject from the top 7 students:

```
SELECT TOP 7 Sum(tblScores.Scores) AS Total, tblScores.AdmissionID
FROM tblScores
WHERE (((tblScores.ExamID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstC]) AND ((tblScores.ClassID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstB]))
GROUP BY tblScores.AdmissionID
ORDER BY Sum(tblScores.Scores) DESC;
```

The  Class and Exam criteria is read from the Form "frmReports"

Any one who can help me out?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What makes the 7 students the best?  What if scores are tied?

Comment: I am not interested in the 7 best students.The sql above would solve that.  I am interested in best scores from 7 subjects (among 10 or 12 attempted) - that would be my desired results. My table has 5 fields (of our concern). These are AdmissionID, ClassID, ExamID, SubjectID and Scores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Parfait - Thank you for your guidance. I have actually tweaked your solution to get a perfect answer: Here is the sql:

SELECT Dupe.AdmissionID, Dupe.Scores, Dupe.ScoreRank
FROM (SELECT qryFilteredScores.AdmissionID, qryFilteredScores.Scores,    (SELECT Count(*) FROM qryFilteredScores AS sub
WHERE sub.AdmissionID = qryFilteredScores.AdmissionID AND sub.Scores >qryFilteredScores.Scores)+ 1 AS ScoreRank FROM qryFilteredScores WHERE (((qryFilteredScores.ExamID)=Forms!frmReports!lstC) And ((qryFilteredScores.ClassID)=Forms!frmReports!lstB)))  AS Dupe
WHERE (((Dupe.Scores)<>0) AND ((Dupe.ScoreRank)<=7));

Alternatively, you can use a derived table or stored query (where you save derived table as separate object referenced in this query) and avoid inline subqueries:

```
SELECT Dupe.AdmissionID, Total.TotalScore
FROM qryFilteredScores AS Dupe
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT sub.AdmissionID, Sum(sub.Scores) As TotalScore
      FROM qryFilteredScores sub
      WHERE ([AdmissionID]=Dupe.[AdmissionID] 
      AND ((sub.ClassID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstB]) 
      AND ((tblScores.ExamID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstC]))
      GROUP BY sub.AdmissionID) AS Total
ON Dupe.AdmissionID = Total.AdmissionID 
GROUP BY Dupe.AdmissionID, Total.TotalScore
ORDER BY Dupe.AdmissionID;
```

Comment: But where in this do you take the top 7 scores per student? You might want to show `qryFilteredScores`. And it will be more efficient to move the subquery to a `JOIN` as no longer are you correlating with outer query but just matching ids.

Comment: The top 7 scores were needed to calculate GPA which is based on the 7 best subject scores. I wanted to avoid function calls in a report that is why I wanted pure sql solution (hence sub queries within the main query) for the report thinking I would have a better performance. I was wrong. The report is taking more than 3 minutes to generate. Thank you again.

Comment: You did not answer my question. Where in your accepted solution do you filter for student's top 7 scores? It is now clearly shown and the named query's content is unknown. Future readers of this post will have difficulty understanding. And why mention function calls? All we do here is SQL. And this query *would* take some time as you run a subquery that can be a joined table, avoiding a separate select for each row of table. See edited alternative.

Comment: @parfait Sorry I forgot to update my final working solution. Thank you for reminding me. It would have definitely confuse other readers. I have edited yours as a final working version

Answer (score 1):

Consider a correlated subquery to calculate a running rank of scores. Then, nest this select query in a derived table for *Score* aggregation, filtered by each students' top 7 scores (including ties):

```
SELECT main.AdmissionID, Sum(main.Scores) As [Total]
FROM
  (SELECT tblScores.AdmissionID, tblScores.Scores,
         (SELECT Count(*) FROM tblScores sub
          WHERE sub.AdmissionID = tblScores.AdmissionID
          AND sub.Scores >= tblScores.Scores) As ScoreRank
   FROM tblScores
   WHERE (((tblScores.ExamID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstC])
     AND  ((tblScores.ClassID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstB]))
  ) As main
WHERE main.ScoreRank <= 7   
GROUP BY main.AdmissionID
```

Comment: @ parfait - The concept sounds fine. But I am having a problem following your example. The filtered part is where i got lost. Can you please explain

Comment: But does it work? Run the nested `SELECT` query wrapped in *main* alias on its own and you will see the *ScoreRank* column of students' scores highest to lowest.

Comment: Then we run another aggregate query using this nested one as the source to take *ScoreRank* 7 or less, meaning top 7 *Scores* per student. In fact, in MS Access you do not need nested subquery but can save that as  a separate query to be referenced in final one.

Comment: By the way, I made a mistake originally using `GROUP BY` in subquery and now removed. See edit.

Comment: @ parfait -  Results are promising, but will need a bit of  tweaking to produce correct results. Though I still don't have an idea where to start. The list produce 31 names which is OK because one student did not attempt all the subject, but the sum of scores of the best 7 subjects doesn't seems to be correct. I am analysing to see if I could pick a pattern of what is omitted. What is evident is that the results are all lower than expected. I even thought may be we picked 7 from lowest but that seems not the case. I will report back once I find the pattern of the error. Thank you very much.

Comment: As mentioned, try running the nested query independently and do a cross check on one student's top 7 scores and see if it equals full query's aggregation.

Comment: @ Parfait - Thank you very very much, with a bit of tweaking your code worked. Here is the final version: SELECT Dupe.AdmissionID, (Select Sum(qryFilteredScores.Scores) From qryFilteredScores Where ([AdmissionID]=Dupe.[AdmissionID] AND ((qryFilteredScores.ClassID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstB]) AND ((tblScores.ExamID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstC]))) AS Total
FROM qryFilteredScores AS Dupe
GROUP BY Dupe.AdmissionID
ORDER BY Dupe.AdmissionID;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 7 Sum(tblScores.Scores) AS Total, tblScores.AdmissionID
FROM tblScores
HAVING (((tblScores.ExamID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstC]) AND ((tblScores.ClassID)=[Forms]![frmReports]![lstB]))
GROUP BY tblScores.AdmissionID
ORDER BY Sum(tblScores.Scores) DESC;
```

Comment: @ Laurence That is what i tried in the first place. I would get total scores for the first best students. What I want is sum of 7 best scores for all the students.

Comment: Indeed, moving condition from `WHERE` to `HAVING` clause should make no difference.